# Trouble defining a function with multiple arguments

Tags: function

I am getting the error message 'Invalid syntax' when defining a function and I don't know why.

def Goldman(PNa, NaO, NaI, PK, KO, KI):
return 60 * np.log10(PNa(NaO/NaI + (PK(KO/KI)))

Goldman(5, 100, 10, 90, 7, 80)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your return statement.

```
def Goldman(PNa, NaO, NaI, PK, KO, KI): 
  return 60 * np.log10(PNa(NaO/NaI + (PK(KO/KI))))

Goldman(5, 100, 10, 90, 7, 80)
```